# How to compare dates doing a test rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Why my test comparing times are failing sometimes? how can i improve this test?

```
data = {  init: Time.zone.now, end: Time.zone.tomorrow }
        put "/api/...", params: data,
            
expect(JSON.parse(response.body)['time'].to_time).to be_within(1.seconds).of(Time.zone.now)
```

I would like to solve this to pass always the test

Comment: What is 2 seconds in your example? Why do you call `Time.zone.now` twice in data?

Comment: @mechnicov i would like to improve my code, so far i am calling Time.zone.now twice for init and end

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you call `Time.now` multiple times and between calls, it may have changed. Better doing something like this:

```
now = Time.zone.now
interval = 10.seconds

data = {  init: now - interval, end: now + interval }
response = put "/api/...", params: data
            
expect(JSON.parse(response.body)['time'].to_time).to be_within(interval).of(now)
```

I would also advise to compare date as integer to prevent any timezone difficulties in your test:

```
response_time = JSON.parse(response.body)['time']
expect(response_time.to_time.to_i).to be_within(interval).of(now.to_i)
```

Comment: i edited a bit my question

Comment: @whatl also edited my answer to fit your question that has changed quite a bit